# Slice into chunks and average (reduce) array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, reduce

I have an array:

`var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];`

that I would like to splice into `[0,1,2]` and `[3,4,5]` followed by averaging it so the final result would be:

`var dataOptimised = [1,4];`

this is what I have found so far:

```
function chunk (arr, len) {

    var chunks = [];
    var i = 0;
    var n = arr.length;

    while (i < n) {
      chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len)); // gives [[0,1,2] [3,4,5]]
    }

    return chunks;

};
```

How to reduce it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want less code to accomplish what you're doing? And are you asking for a solution that works dynamically based on the array's size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sum each chunk using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and divide by the chunk's `length`.

```js
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

function chunkAverage(arr, len) {
    var chunks = [];
    var i = 0;
    var n = arr.length;
    
    var chunk;

    while (i < n) {
      chunk = arr.slice(i, i += len);
      chunks.push(
        chunk.reduce((s, n) => s + n) / chunk.length
      );
    }

    return chunks;
};

console.log(chunkAverage(data, 3));
```

Comment: Just use the chunk length as the divider. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can `map` the array and `reduce` it.

```js
function chunk(arr, len) {
  var chunks = [];
  var i = 0;
  var n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len)); // gives [[0,1,2] [3,4,5]]
  }

  return chunks;
};

var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var result = chunk(data, 3).map(o => (o.reduce((c, v) => c + v, 0)) / o.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the array in half using `splice`. And use `.reduce` to take sum and average finally

```js
var arrR = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arrL = arrR.splice(0, Math.ceil(arrR.length / 2)),
    results = [getAverave(arrL), getAverave(arrR)];
console.log(results)

function getAverave(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / arr.length;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sortest answer possible for this question.
n is the index you want to slice from.

```
function chunk (arr, n) {
   return [Math.sum.apply(null, arr.slice(0, n)), Math.sum.apply(null, arr.slice(n, arr.length))];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), you can use the `_.chunk()` function to easily chunk your array, then `map()` each chunk to a `reduce()` function which averages each chunk.

When importing the `underscore.js` library, you can reference the library using the `_` symbol.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const len = 3;

const result = _.chunk(arr, len).map(chunk => chunk.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / chunk.length);
console.log(result); // Outputs [1, 4]
```

If you have an odd-length array; say that `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, then `result` would be `[1, 4, 6]`.

In HTML, you can include the library in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32te6e2t/) where you can see it in action (you'll have to open the F12 tools to see console output; the StackOverflow embedded snippets are kind of funky and don't work right).

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with both Ori Drori and Eddie, but I thought I might also provide some additional minor changes to your `chunk` function for consistency and maintainability's sake...

When writing JavaScript, I would recommend using function names that won't collide with common/expected variable names. For example, with a function like `chunk()` that returns a "chunk", it's likely you would want to create a variable called `chunk` to hold its return value. A line of code like `var chunk = chunk()` is an obvious problem, but if it gets any less direct it can easily wreak havoc down the line. Using the `const var = function` pattern (see snippet) helps you avoid writing over the original function by throwing an error on the correct line, but I would argue it's also still good to get in the habit of using a naming convention that doesn't have this drawback just in case you can't use something like `const`. My approach is to always include a verb in the function name. In your case, "chunk" can also be considered a verb, but it conflicts. So, I prefixed it with "get".

```js
const getChunk = (arr, len) => {
    const chunks = []
    const n = arr.length
    let i = 0

    while (i < n) {
      chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len))
    }

    return chunks
}

const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

const optimizedData =
  getChunk(data, 3).map(chunk =>
    chunk.reduce((total, val) => total + val) / chunk.length
)

console.log(optimizedData)
```